# How to draw this bow tie pattern using Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to draw the following pattern using Python While Loops.

[image]

I have spent quite a lot of time and came up with this code which prints it perfectly but this code is so much long and I feel like it is not one of those good codes.

If anybody here can help me out shrinking this code or suggesting a better way to output?

here is the code:

```
#Question 10, Alternate Approach
temp = 1
pattern = ""
innerSpace = 7
starCount = 1
while temp <= 5:
    st = 1
    while st <= starCount:
        pattern = pattern + "*"
        if st != starCount:
            pattern = pattern + " "
        st = st + 1
    sp = 0
    if temp == 5:
            innerSpace = 1
    while sp < innerSpace:
        pattern = pattern + " "
        sp = sp  + 1
    st = 1
    while st <= starCount:
        if temp == 5:
            st = st + 1
        pattern = pattern + "*"
        if st != starCount:
            pattern = pattern + " "
        st = st + 1
    temp = temp + 1
    innerSpace = innerSpace - 2
    pattern = pattern + "\n"
    if temp % 2 == 0:
        pattern = pattern + " "
    else:
        starCount = starCount + 1
starCount = 2
innerSpace = 1
while temp > 5 and temp <= 9:
    st = 1
    while st <= starCount:
        pattern = pattern + "*"
        if st != starCount:
            pattern = pattern + " "
        st = st + 1
    sp = 0
    while sp < innerSpace:
        pattern = pattern + " "
        sp = sp  + 1
    st = 1
    while st <= starCount:
        pattern = pattern + "*"
        if st != starCount:
            pattern = pattern + " "
        st = st + 1
    temp = temp + 1
    innerSpace = innerSpace + 2
    pattern = pattern + "\n"
    if temp % 2 == 0:
        starCount = starCount - 1
        pattern = pattern + " "        
print pattern
```

Comment: Nope, its not. That bowtie has different pattern as compared to mine.

Comment: modify it, that's what programmers do!

Comment: Consider rendering to a temporary (random-access) buffer rather than directly to a stream. Perhaps `collections.defaultdict`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this looks like an assignment, I'll give you a hint how I would do it.

Take advantage of the symmetry of the bow. It is symmetrical about the horizontal and vertical axis. Therefore, you really only need to solve 1 corner, then copy/mirror the results to get the rest.

This code gives one way of looking at the problem, which is just shifting a initial string (the middle of the bow) to get the desired shape:

```
m      = '*'
size   = 4
n      = 5 # must be odd
pad    = ' ' * n
middle = (m + pad) * size
half   = int(n / 2) + 1

print middle
print middle[half*1:]
print middle[half*2:]
print middle[half*3:]
print middle[half*4:]
print middle[half*5:]
print middle[half*6:]
```

Which yields this:

```
*     *     *     *
   *     *     *
*     *     *
   *     *
*     *
   *
*
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Using a stars and spacing and counting variable

```
counting=1
star_amount=1
space_amount=6
loop_var=7
while loop_var>0:
    loop_var-=1
    if space_amount==0:
        counting*=-1
    stars=" * "*star_amount
    spaces="   "*space_amount
    print(stars+spaces+stars)
    star_amount+=counting
    space_amount-= counting*2
```

Comment: @HenrySpike That is not specified in the original question.

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton and I tried it. Though there is a bug, the last two statements should be: star_amount+=counting and space_amount+=counting

Comment: perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would use list comprehensions and strings and would exploit the symmetry of the figure.

Not a complete solution, but could be a part of a loop body

```
In [2]: a = '*' + ' '*8

In [3]: a
Out[3]: '*        '
In [24]: result = ''

In [25]: result += a

In [26]: result
Out[26]: '*        '

In [27]: result += a[-1::-1]

In [28]: result
Out[28]: '*                *'

In [29]: result += '\n'

In [30]: a = ' '+'*' + ' '*7

In [31]: a
Out[31]: ' *       '

In [32]: result += a

In [33]: result += a[-1::-1]

In [34]: result += '\n'

In [36]: print result
*                *
 *              *
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you use *while* loop much as if they where *for* loops.
I don't think that's what your teacher wants.

The idea behind *while* is to run until a certain condition is met, not
necessarily when the number of iterations exceed a certain limit.

The condition does not need to be included in the while statement, you can check it later and use the *break* command to escape the loop

Try for example this:

```
start = '*'
while True:
    print start
    if start[0] == '*':
        start = ' ' + start
    else:
        start = '*' + start        
    if (start == '* * *'):
        break
```

output is just a part of your assignment, think you should be able to work it out to the final, expected result!

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully by this time HW is done. Since I solved this using `dynamic programming`, I thought I would list solution here.

Observations:
While looking at pattern its observed that bottom half is `palindrome` of top half. Hence we need to calculate only the top half.

Next we see that for every row count,we have pattern like,
row 1 = 1 , n
row 2 = 2 , n -1
row 3 = 1,3, n-2, n
row 4 = 2, 4 , n-3, n-1
.. and so on.

With iteration index as row count and `n` as input value we can dynamically calculate remaining values very efficiently.

**Source-Code**

```
def get_list(bound, alist):
    tmp_list = []
    for i in xrange(1,bound + 1):
        tmp_list.append(star if i in alist else dot)
    return tmp_list

star = "*"
dot = " "

n = 20 #How large of BowTie do you want?
m = (n * 2) - 1

#get  top half list
th = []
for idx,k in enumerate(xrange(1,n+1)): #run through 1 - n
    row = idx + 1
    tmplst = []
    if row % 2 != 0:
        tmplst.append(i for i in xrange(1,row + 1) if i % 2 != 0)
        tmplst.append(i for i in xrange(m, m-row, -1) if i % 2 != 0)
    else:
        tmplst.append(i for i in xrange(1,row + 1) if i % 2 == 0)
        tmplst.append(i for i in xrange(m, m-row, -1) if i % 2 == 0)
    #append each row value to  top half list.
    th.append(sorted(set([j for i in tmplst for j in i])))

#create palindrome of top half which is our bottom half 
th = th + th[len(th) -2::-1]

#create list of * and blanks
final = [get_list(m, i) for i in th]

#Print BowTie
for i in final:
    print ' '.join(i)
```